# In which orientations do two planar magnetic shells have maximum attraction/repulsion and no force?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetostatics

A very thin magnet (one side +ve and other side -ve) is called a magnetic shell.

[image]

Now for two *planar* magnetic shells placed near to each other with unlike poles facing each other, there will be attraction.

[image]

Now if we keep tilting the second shell, the attractive force would decrease and then becomes repulsive and by turning it around $180^0$ it becomes highly repulsive (as shown below).

[image]

**What I need to know is, while keeping the first planar shell in same orientation, by tilting the second planar shell by certain angles, in which angles there would be maximum attraction, maximum repulsion and no force?**

Comment: To be clear, are the diagrams meant to depict the tiles as coaxial (instead of coplanar)? The 3D layout is a bit hard to gauge from the pictures.

Comment: No, the tiles are coplanar

Comment: That's a weird understanding of "facing each other", but in any case you should edit the question to make the geometry clear.

Comment: Unlike poles attract each other. Now whatever be the orientation of second shell, if they attract, I called them "unlike poles facing each other".

Comment: I would say they're not facing each other any more than, say, the [Chain Bridge lions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoGNK.jpg) do, but ultimately, bear this in mind: unclear language begets unclear communication, and that is never in your favour. If people point out that your diagrams or language are ambiguous, you do need to act to clarify both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a good approximation, the force between the two magnets can be modelled as [the force between two magnetic dipoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole#Forces_between_two_magnetic_dipoles) of dipole moments $\mathbf m_1$ and $\mathbf m_2$ (i.e. vectors which point from the south poles to the north poles along the symmetry axis of the shells), separated by a displacement $\mathbf r$, given by
$$
{\displaystyle \mathbf {F} (\mathbf {r} ,\mathbf {m} _{1},\mathbf {m} _{2})={\dfrac {3\mu _{0}}{4\pi r^{5}}}\left[(\mathbf {m} _{1}\cdot \mathbf {r} )\mathbf {m} _{2}+(\mathbf {m} _{2}\cdot \mathbf {r} )\mathbf {m} _{1}+(\mathbf {m} _{1}\cdot \mathbf {m} _{2})\mathbf {r} -{\dfrac {5(\mathbf {m} _{1}\cdot \mathbf {r} )(\mathbf {m} _{2}\cdot \mathbf {r} )}{r^{2}}}\mathbf {r} \right]}.
$$

---

Following the simplest reading of the diagrams in the question, with the shells sharing an axis, you're fixing $\mathbf m_1$ to be antiparallel to $\hat{\mathbf r}=\mathbf r/r$, so you have
$$
\mathbf {F} (\mathbf {r} ,-m_1 \hat{\mathbf r},\mathbf {m} _{2})
=
\frac {3\mu _{0}m_1}{4\pi}
\frac{1}{r^4}
\left[
3(\mathbf {m} _{2}\cdot \hat{\mathbf r}) \hat{\mathbf r}
-\mathbf {m} _{2}
 \right].
$$
This then means that

- if $\mathbf m_2=-m_2 \hat{\mathbf r}$ points towards the first shell, then
  $$
  \mathbf {F} (\mathbf {r} ,-m_1 \hat{\mathbf r},-m_2 \hat{\mathbf r})
  =
  -2m_2  \hat{\mathbf r}
  \frac {3\mu _{0}m_1}{4\pi}
  \frac{1}{r^4}
  $$
  and the force is attractive,
- if $\mathbf m_2=+m_2 \hat{\mathbf r}$ points away from the first shell, then
  $$
  \mathbf {F} (\mathbf {r} ,-m_1 \hat{\mathbf r},+m_2 \hat{\mathbf r})
  =
  +2 m_2 \hat{\mathbf r}
  \frac {3\mu _{0}m_1}{4\pi}
  \frac{1}{r^4}
  $$
  and the force is repulsive, and
- if $\mathbf m_2\cdot\mathbf r=0$ and the second shell is orthogonal to the existing distance, then the force
  $$
  \mathbf {F} (\mathbf {r} ,-m_1 \hat{\mathbf r},\mathbf {m} _{2})
  =
  -\mathbf {m} _{2}
  \frac {3\mu _{0}m_1}{4\pi}
  \frac{1}{r^4}
  $$
  is neither attractive nor repulsive; instead, it tries to bring swing the second shell around.

---

If, instead, the shells are coplanar, then $\mathbf m_1\cdot\mathbf r=0$ as the shells' centres' separation is always orthogonal to the axis of the first one, so the force is instead given by
$$
\mathbf {F} (\mathbf {r} ,\mathbf {m} _{1},\mathbf {m} _{2})
=
\dfrac {3\mu _{0}}{4\pi r^{5}}\left[
(\mathbf {m} _{2}\cdot \mathbf {r} )\mathbf {m} _{1}
+(\mathbf {m} _{1}\cdot \mathbf {m} _{2})\mathbf {r} 
\right]
.
$$
This tells you that the force is in general neither fully attractive nor fully repulsive, and it is only zero if $\mathbf m_2$ is orthogonal to both the initial dipole and the mutual separation. In any case, the line-of-sight component
$$
(\mathbf {F} (\mathbf {r} ,\mathbf {m} _{1},\mathbf {m} _{2}) \cdot \hat{\mathbf r})\hat{\mathbf r}
=
\dfrac {3\mu _{0}}{4\pi r^{4}}
(\mathbf {m} _{1}\cdot \mathbf {m} _{2})\hat{\mathbf r}
.
$$
can be attractive if $\mathbf {m} _{1}\cdot \mathbf {m} _{2}<0$ and the magnetic moments are pointing in opposite directions, repulsive if $\mathbf {m} _{1}\cdot \mathbf {m} _{2}$ and the two shells have the poles aligned, and $\mathbf {m} _{1}\cdot \mathbf {m} _{2}=0$ and the second magnetic moment is in the same orthogonal plane as $\hat{\mathbf r}$.

Comment: If $\vec{m}_1$, $\vec{m}_2$, and $\vec{r}$ are all coplanar (i.e., you rotate $\vec{m}_2$ about an axis perpendicular to $\vec{r}$), and $\vec{m}_1$ is orthogonal to $\vec{r}$, then you're correct that the force will never vanish.  However, if $\vec{m}_1$, $\vec{m}_2$, and $\vec{r}$ are all mutually orthogonal, then your analysis implies that the force *will* vanish.  You can accomplish this by rotating $\vec{m}_2$ about $\vec{r}$ by 90° rather than rotating about an axis perpendicular to $\vec{r}$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Ah, yes, of course.